Request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
I have a complex Prometheus query that runs successfully and quickly in Thanos but consistently times out in Grafana on big time range like 120 days. The query is as follows:
avg(sum_over_time(
  (sum by(container)(kube_pod_container_status_running{namespace=~"keycloak|dev", container=~"keycloak|test-server|test-web"}) >= bool 1)[$__range:]
) / count_over_time(
  (sum by(container)(kube_pod_container_status_running{namespace=~"keycloak|dev", container=~"keycloak|test-server|test-web"}))[$__range:]
) * 100)

with this query I want to get the global availability of my applications.
The query works perfectly in Thanos without timeouts.
Grafana still times out despite increasing the timeout settings.
The memory usage of thanos-storegateway is high, but it’s managed within the increased resource limits.
Why does the query time out in Grafana but not in Thanos?
Are there other settings in Grafana or Thanos that I should adjust?
or is there a way to simplify the query ?
I would be really thankful if anyone have any ideas to help me

It could be that step of the query evaluation has this affect. How are you running this in Thanos? And does you query has ticked "Instant" option in Grafana?

Also, just as a sidenote: IIUC whole sum_over_time/count_over_time can be replaced with avg_over_time. Doubt this will have an effect on performance, but query will be definitely easier to read.

I have a gauge graph, and the instant option is not checked. but i am trying to have an average of the up time of my pods in kubernetes. if I were to check the "Instant" option, my understanding is that it would only return the value at the end of the specified time range, rather than an average over the entire range. Is this correct?

Instant means you get a single result on the end of range, with average over that range. But not Instant (Range, IIRC) means you get results for every tick of time for all 120 days.

This is similar to tabs Table and Graph in Prometheus' web console (IDK if the console is the same for Thanos)
